# Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'. Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Please find below files

**1.app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.mood_reader_demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
}
```

**2. android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

3. pubspec.yaml

   environment:
   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

   dependencies:
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
   get: ^4.1.4
   image_picker: ^0.7.4
   firebase_core: ^1.0.3
   firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.10
   firebase_auth: ^1.1.0

   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

   dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter

   flutter:

   uses-material-design: true

**4. Error**

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
  > > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
  > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)

  ```
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
  ```

  - Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 23s
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done

Comment: Do invalidate cache and restart from AS

Comment: Did already. but still same issue

Comment: See the error it clearly says duplicate found in `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.1.0`. Both are same , just diff version  Did you recently updated dependencies ?

Comment: yes.. I have updated.. but after doing invalidate cache and restart still its behaving same.. I have also saw same error but not able to find 19.1.0

Comment: Do `flutter clean` , if that doesn't help. Go to `yourAppFolder->android.` Open cmd do `gradlew clean`

Comment: Tried. Still its same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did below changes in my app/build.gradle

Removed

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
```

Also, need to match your dependencies in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Kotlin version from 1.7.10 to 1.8.0 in `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0' // was 1.7.10
  ...
```